# Create a new column based on values in an existing column

Tags: python-3.x, regex, pandas, dataframe

I would like to create a new column to classify if certain address is a residential or non-residential address.

Below is a column in the original dataframe:

| Building_name |
| --- |
| Fung Chak House, Choi Wan (II) Estate |
| Princess Margaret Hospital (non-residential) |

And I write the below code to create a new column if the string "non-residential" is in Building_name it would be classified as Non-residential, otherwise it would be Residential.

```
def build_cat(row):
    if "(non-residential)" not in district_df['Building_name']:
        return ("Residential")
    if '(non-residential)' in district_df['Building_name']:
        return ('Non_residential')

district_df['Building_category'] = district_df.apply(lambda row: build_cat(row), axis =1)
```

However, the about function returns everything as Residential.

| Building_name | Building_cateory |
| --- | --- |
| Fung Chak House, Choi Wan (II) Estate | Residential |
| Princess Margaret Hospital (non-residential) | Residential |

Appreciate if you can let me know what's wrong in my code, or if there are other more efficient ways to get the same result.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

or use `np.where` as python if-else ternary Operators

```
cond = district_df['Building_name'].str.contains(r'\(non-residential\)')
district_df['Building_cateory'] = np.where(cond, 'Non_residential', 'Residential')
```

---

apply function to the target column `Building_name`.

```
def build_cat(x):
    if "(non-residential)" not in x:
        return "Residential"
    else:
        return 'Non_residential'
district_df['Building_category'] = district_df['Building_name'].map(build_cat)
```

Comment: Timing profiling for the first method: `1.03 ms ± 116 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)` and the timing for the second `742 µs ± 112 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)`

Answer (score 2):

I chose to add this community wiki, for study:

on my Jupyter Notebook, I compared the answers from @MayankPorwal and @Ferris. Here is the result:

First, the `str.contains` with `np.where` method:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'Building_name': ['Fung Chak House, Choi Wan (II) Estate', 'Princess Margaret Hospital (non-residential)', 'Fung Chak 1', 'Fung Chak 2 (non-residential)', 'Fung Chak 3']})

df = pd.concat([df] * 10000, ignore_index=True)

def prop():
    df['Building_cateory'] = np.where(df.Building_name.str.contains('non-residential'), 'Non-residential', 'residential')
```

Now, timing it:

```py
%timeit prop()
```

The result:

```bash
81.1 ms ± 15.5 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

On the other hand, the `map()` approach:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'Building_name': ['Fung Chak House, Choi Wan (II) Estate', 'Princess Margaret Hospital (non-residential)', 'Fung Chak 1', 'Fung Chak 2 (non-residential)', 'Fung Chak 3']})

df = pd.concat([df] * 10000, ignore_index=True)

def prop():
    def build_cat(x):
        if "(non-residential)" not in x:
            return "Residential"
        else:
            return 'Non_residential'
    df['Building_category'] = df['Building_name'].map(build_cat)
```

Now, timing it:

```py
%timeit prop()
```

The result:

```bash
15.7 ms ± 1.13 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

---

Thus, we have a clear winner!

Comment: @jezrael, used your idea for increasing the size of the dataset!

Comment: guys thank you very much. I'm a beginner but what confuse me most is there are so many different ways you can go to have the same result in python. Thank you.

Comment: @1cjtcjj Please un-accept the community wiki, and accept the answer, in-my-honest-opinion, by @Ferris, since he deserves the credit. As to `there are so many different ways you can go to have the same result in python`, yeah, that is the beauty of python.

Comment: sorry about my mistake bcos I'm new to both python and stackoverflow. I now switch the credit to Ferris. thanks for the helps anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following `pandas` trick to do it <s>faster</s>:

---

**Edit**

*Nope, applying lambda is faster.*

Timing using the `str.contains` approach:

```bash
2.34 ms ± 367 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Timing using the apply-lambda approach:

```bash
1.08 ms ± 138 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Using the `map()` approach is **fastest**:

```bash
742 µs ± 112 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

---

Please note, the new column `Building_category` is created after `#Line 1`

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Building_name': ['Fung Chak House, Choi Wan (II) Estate', 'Princess Margaret Hospital (non-residential)']})

# Line 1
df.loc[df[df['Building_name'].str.contains('(non-residential)')].index, 'Building_category'] = "Non_Residential"

# Line 2
df.loc[df[~df['Building_name'].str.contains('(non-residential)')].index, 'Building_category'] = "Residential"

print(df)
```

Output generated:

```bash
                                  Building_name Building_category
0         Fung Chak House, Choi Wan (II) Estate       Residential
1  Princess Margaret Hospital (non-residential)   Non_Residential
```

Comment: Do you try 10k, 100k rows for test?

Comment: @jezrael, nope, since I do not have the data!

Comment: Try `df = pd.concat([df] * 1000, ignore_index=True)`

Comment: I think the correct way to use `str.contains` would be to use `np.where` for setting the values like @Ferris has done in the answer, as opposed to two separate lines I have used!

Answer (score 1):

Use [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
In [1197]: import numpy as np

In [1198]: df['Building_cateory'] = np.where(df.Building_name.str.contains('non-residential'), 'Non-residential', 'residential')

In [1199]: df
Out[1199]: 
                                  Building_name  Building_cateory
0         Fung Chak House, Choi_Wan (II) Estate       residential
1  Princess Margaret Hospital (non-residential)   Non-residential
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure this is the best way to go. Yet, relating to your precise question of unexpected result you got, please change `district_df` to `row`in your function. Like this.
For a better approach, take a looks at other answer belows. Kr.

````
    def build_cat(row):
        if "(non-residential)" not in row['Building_name']:
            return ("Residential")
        if '(non-residential)' in row['Building_name']:
            return ('Non_residential')
    
    district_df['Building_category'] = district_df.apply(lambda row: build_cat(row), axis =1) 
    ```
````